# Dealining with missing values in multiple columns of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I am dealing with a huge dataframe with hundreds of columns with possibility of missing values in each of the columns. Here is sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'a':  [1,1,0,1,1],
        'b': ["a", "b", np.nan, 'c', np.nan],
        'c': ['b1','b2',np.nan, 'c1', np.nan],
        'd': [1,1,1, 2, np.nan],
        'e': [4,4,4, 3, np.nan]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   a    b    c    d    e
0  1    a   b1  1.0  4.0
1  1    b   b2  1.0  4.0
2  0  NaN  NaN  1.0  4.0
3  1    c   c1  2.0  3.0
4  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

In order to deal with missing values at once, I am doing something like this. Which basically if the missing values are in one the a,b, or c columns, then I replace them with a specific value.

```
df=df.fillna({'a':0, 'b':'other', 'c':-1})
print (df)
   a      b   c    d    e
0  1      a  b1  1.0  4.0
1  1      b  b2  1.0  4.0
2  0  other  -1  1.0  4.0
3  1      c  c1  2.0  3.0
4  1  other  -1  NaN  NaN
```

What I would like to do is if the missing values in any other columns than those three columns, then simply replace the missing values with a value that appears the most often in that column. For example, in `column d`, 1 is repeated the most so I simply replace missing value in with `1.0`.

Comment: what happens if you have a tie? eg. with `[1, 2, 1, 2, NaN]`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a single [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) or are fine with getting the first value:

```
d = {'a':0, 'b':'other', 'c':-1}
d2 = df.drop(columns=list(d)).mode().loc[0].to_dict()

out = df.fillna(d|d2) # requires python 3.9+

# for 3.5 <= python < 3.9
# out = df.fillna({**d, **d2})
```

Output:

```
   a      b   c    d    e
0  1      a  b1  1.0  4.0
1  1      b  b2  1.0  4.0
2  0  other  -1  1.0  4.0
3  1      c  c1  2.0  3.0
4  1  other  -1  1.0  4.0
```